# How do you count the number of hops?

Tags: linux, networking, traceroute

I'm trying to connect to the GAN (Internet) and my final network node is `10.200.0.1`

How do I count the number of Hops to reach this final network node? I've tried `traceroute 10.200.0.1` But it only gave me a number of **`30 hops max`** How do you find the number of hops over that?

Comment: See `man traceroute`, the `-m` option.

Answer (score 1):

To raise the number of max hops see the comment of Kusalananda, for example to probe for at least 40 hops

```
traceroute -m 40 10.200.0.1
```

To answer how to *count* the number of hops: traceroute offers (as far as I know) no option to explicitly only output the number of hops. You may use awk:

```
traceroute -m 40 10.200.0.1 | awk 'END{print $1}'
```

END rule is executed once only, after all the input is read. So `print $1` will output the first column of last output, in your case the maximum hops.

**EDIT 1:**

You should consider traceroute uses ICMP requests. Not every hop does respond ICMP packets. The number of hops may vary significant if you use -T option (-T: use TCP SYN for probes)

Answer (score 0):

man traceroute:

```
   -m max_ttl, --max-hops=max_ttl
          Specifies  the  maximum  number of hops (max time-to-live value)
          traceroute will probe. The default is 30.
```

Btw. 30 hops should be enough for everyone. :->